# Inconsistency while using Positive Lookahead

Tags: regex

I am trying figure out how things actually work with positive lookahead. While trying so, I have reached a point where I want to capture anything between
ABC and PQR which includes 'mao' somewhere in between ABC and PQR.

Things seem to be working with that:

```
ABC(?=.*?mao).*?PQR
```

It is matching fine except in one case, watch my screenshot for that:

[image]

I thought the red marked block shouldn't have been matched.

[I have tried it here](https://regex101.com/r/U9rFNR/3)

Can anybody please explain what I am doing wrong here and Why is it matched ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?=.*?mao)` can find `mao` *after* `PQR` because a `.` matches any character (if DOTALL mode is not ON, all except linebreak symbols). In `zxcABCdddddddPQRaasd which contains mao inside`, the `mao` appears after any 0+ chars other than linebreaks symbols on the same line with `PQR`, so the lookahead returns *true*.

To avoid that, use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
ABC(?=(?:(?!PQR).)*mao).*?PQR
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/LwHozA/1) (you may also use `*?` instead of `*`, that will just make it lazy).

The `(?=(?:(?!PQR).)*mao)` construct will only return *true* if `mao` appears after 0+ chars that do not start the `PQR` character sequence (that is, if `PQR` does not appear before `mao`).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit why, The "(?=.*?mao)" can find mao after PQR ?

Comment: "In zxcABCdddddddPQRaasd which contains mao inside, the mao appears after any 0+ chars other than linebreaks symbols on the same line with PQR, so the lookahead returns true."  --- I have set a boundary PQR why does this go beyond it , I think I have some problem in concept

Comment: Yes, `.*?mao` explanation is: `.*?` matches any zero or more chars other than linebreak symbols, as few as possible, but as many as necessary to return a valid match, up to the first `mao`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "capture anything between ABC and PQR which includes 'mao' somewhere in between ABC and PQR", you do not need to include the `.*` in the look-ahead. Just use:

```
ABC.*(?=mao).*PQR
```

[Test yourself](https://regex101.com/r/yNNd2N/1)

**Edit:** Oh my, it's a bit early - To meet your requirement as given in the question, it's not needed to use a look-ahead at all. This is enough:

```
ABC.*mao.*PQR
```

Of course this has problems with reappearing start (`ABC`) and end (`PQR`) tokens, like in `ABCandABCmaoPQR` and `ABCmaoPQRmaoPQR`, where it might match more that you'd like it too. [I've updated the regex here to include these sample cases](https://regex101.com/r/yNNd2N/2).

**Edit 2:** Just seen that one of your test strings `ABC1234sakasdf mao mao aslkdfPQR dsfgasd mao maoPQR` already covers what I've noted in the paragraph above. I need a coffee.

Comment: Note that `ABC.*(?=mao).*PQR` regex does not work the same as OP regex as it matches up to the last `PQR` that has `mao` before it. If you change it to `ABC.*?mao.*?PQR`, it will be closer, but it will also match `ABC 1 PQR mao aslkdf PQR` - not sure it is expected.